# dojo Moveable events?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events

I am reading the documentation here http://bill.dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojo/dnd/move.parentConstrainedMoveable and here http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dnd/Moveable.html and some examples found around the web but I don't seem to understand how to make it work. I have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W7V2a/4/ I want before the move starts to call a function, during the move to call another function and once it ends a third function. Not only once but every time a move happens. I can't make it catch the events.

Also buttons will be added and removed all the time so attaching the moveable object to a variable like

```
var moveable = new move.parentConstrainedMoveable(button.domNode, {
        handle: this.focusNode,
        area: "content",
        within: true
    });

    on(moveable, "onMoveStart", function (e) {
        dojo.query(".container").style("backgroundColor", "red");
        alert("onMoveStart");
    });
```

doesn't seem practical. So how can I create moveable objects on the fly and catch their events and do something with these events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working with the `dojo/on` module, you only need to pass the **name** of the event. In your case, you have to replace `"onMove"` by `"Move"` and `"onMoveStart"` by `"MoveStart"`, like this:

```
on(moveable, "MoveStart", function (e) {
    dojo.query(".container").style("backgroundColor", "red");
    alert("onMoveStart");
});

on(moveable, "Move", function (e) {
    dojo.query(".container").style("backgroundColor", "red");
    alert("onMove");
});
```

I also updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7V2a/8/ (though I don't recommend using `alert()`).

---

You only have to work with the full name if you're directly working with the function itself. So for example, if you're using the `dojo/aspect` module, you will have to use:

```
aspect.after(moveable, "onMove", function(e) {
    dojo.query(".container").style("backgroundColor", "red");
    alert("onMove");
});
```

---

However, `dojo/on` is normally only used for **DOM event handling** and not for custom events. The best way to use these events is by using the [`on()`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojo/dnd/Moveable#1%5f9dojo%5fdnd%5fMoveable%5fon) function on the `moveable` itself, for example:

```
moveable.on("Move", function (e) {
   dojo.query(".container").style("backgroundColor", "red");
   alert("onMove");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So I have 3 options now. object.on(), aspect and dojo/on.

Comment: Yes, but they have different use cases. As I explained, `dojo/on` is mainly for DOM events while `dojo/aspect` is rather being used for normal functions (non-events). But as you have seen, all 3 will work fine :)